# Where does the term 'dense' used in forcing/Martin's axiom come from?

Tags: general-topology, logic, set-theory, terminology, forcing

There are some common meanings to 'dense' in Mathematics.

- In Topology, a subset $S\subseteq X$ of a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is dense if the intersection of every non-empty open set with $S$ is non-empty.
- In linear order theory, if $(X,<)$ is linearly ordered and $S\subseteq X$, $S$ is dense if for every $x<y$ there is an $s\in S$ such that $x<s<y$.

In forcing or Martin's axiom, dense is defined as a subset $S\subseteq P$ of a partially ordered set $(P,\le)$ such that for all $x\in P$ there is an $s\in S$ such that $s\le x$.

The definition resembles more the definition of a filter-base (with the entire $P$ being the filter).  Why is the term 'dense' used for this property?  Is there a historical basis for this that predates forcing?

The definition can be made a particular case of the topological one by taking as basis for a topology on $P$ sets of the form $\{y\colon y\le x\}$ for $x\in P$.  This seems contrived.  The definition of dense on a linear order can also be made topological by taking the topology with open intervals as a base.  This is more historical, as the topology on $\Bbb{R}$ was always defined via the linear order.

Comment: Why is the definition of the order topology "contrived"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  I didn't say the order topology on a totally-ordered set is contrived.  I said calling this concept 'dense' because of the topology $\{y\colon y\le x\}$ is contrived.  This concept of dense is equivalent to saying that $D$ is co-final in the opposite order of $\le$.  So a more fitting term is downward-confinal or co-initial.  In the usual order on $\Bbb{R}$ this definition of dense is to say that $D$ is not bounded below.  This is very far from the usual meaning of dense.  The word is already used for something.

Comment: If you're thinking about forcing and topology in terms of posets, you really want to think about them, at the least, as being separative. In that case, any totally ordered set collapses to a single point, which, of course, makes the definition of dense become quite reasonable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Fair enough, that applies to forcing.  But then Martin's axiom adopts the term 'dense' as if it's relevant to all posets and restricts the poset with some other set of conditions.  In a different context - a subset of an ordinal being cofinal is also equivalent to being dense in a topology with base $\{y\colon y\ge x\}$ and yet nobody calls that 'dense' and nobody calls the cofinality the 'density' of the ordinal which is the term from topology for the least cardinality of a dense subet.

Comment: But, again, Martin's axiom is a *forcing* axiom. It needs to be taken in the context of forcing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  It doesn't exclude linear orders.  Every linear order has the ccc.  Anyways, see my last comment to the posted answer.

Comment: No, it does not exclude linear orders. Just that they are forcing equivalent to a point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant space isn't $P$ itself, but rather the space $\mathsf{MF}(P)$ of **maximal filters** through $P$ with topology generated by sets of the form $$U_p:=\{H: p\in H\}$$ for $p\in P$. For example, if we take $P$ to be $2^{<\omega}$ (an inessential variant of Cohen forcing), then $\mathsf{MF}(P)$ is just Cantor space $2^\omega$ with the usual topology. A set of conditions $D\subseteq P$ is dense in the forcing sense iff the corresponding set $$\bigcup_{p\in D}U_p$$ is dense - indeed, dense open - in the topological sense. And this is not contrived at all; this is the translation which makes clear the relationship between forcing and the Baire category theorem (see also [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342346/in-simple-words-what-does-woodins-axiom-and-martins-maximum-state/4342571#4342571)).

Comment: Why is that equivalent?  $\bigcup_{p\in D}U_p$ is always open, but saying it's dense is equivalent to saying that for all $x\in P$ there is a $d\in D$ and a maximal filter $U$ such that $x,d\in U$.  Does this imply that for all $x\in P$ there is a $d\in D$ such that $d\le x$?

Comment: @ChadK Yes, it does. Reason contrapositively: if $D$ were not dense in the poset sense, then let $x$ be a condition with no element of $D$ stronger than it and consider $U_x$. (It's generally easier to reason from the poset context to the filters context, so we argue "If $D$ is poset-dense ..." and "If $D$ is not poset-dense ..." to establish the two parts of this equivalence.)

Comment: Working in $\text{ZFC}$ with $\beta\Bbb{N}$.  We have $(P,\le)=(\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})\setminus\emptyset,\subseteq)$.  Let $D=\{\{i,i+1\}\colon i\text{ even}\}$.  Then $D$ is not dense in $P$ in the sense of forcing.  However, $U_p$ for $p\in D$ is the pair of principal ultrafilters on $i, i+1$.  Since $\bigcup_{p\in D}U_p$ contains all principal ultrafilters, it is dense in $\beta\Bbb{N}$.

Comment: In fact, for $D\subseteq P$, $\bigcup_{p\in D}U_p$ is dense in $\beta\Bbb{N}$ iff $\bigcup D=\Bbb{N}$.  On the other hand, $D$ is dense in the sense of forcing iff $\{\{n\}\colon n\in\Bbb{N}\}\subseteq D$.  This is much stricter

Comment: I think the definition of 'dense' in Martin's axiom can be changed to say 'For all $x\in P$ there is a $d\in D$ and $r\in P$ such that $r\le x, r\le d$', while keeping the same outcomes.  This definition of denseness is equivalent in $\text{ZFC}$ to $\bigcup_{p\in D}U_p$ being dense.  The proof of $\text{MA}(\aleph_0)$ then does look exactly like the proof of the Baire Category Theorem.